# Global Atomic Map in netty

Tags: netty

I need to keep a Map(atomic that can handle put,remove,and replace methods) globally, is it a good idea to use ChannelLocal like this:

```
public final static ChannelLocal<Map<String, Integer>> globalMap = new ChannelLocal<Map<String, Integer>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah thats exactly the use-case for ChannelLocal.

Comment: cool thanks, and i will add (true); so it get cleared when channel closes.

Comment: Yeah that is the way to go ;)